# How to use a fixed number of multi-processes in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to analyze the results of different benchmark evaluations.
I have many benchmarks, and when running on the server, I want to evaluate 10 in parallel at a time. In my python script, there is a function that does the evaluation.

```
def load_single_stat(benchmark,prefetcher, retry=False)
```

But every time the function is called, the execution will continue only if the function returns.

I can write a shell script to run ten python scripts.

```
  for((i=0;i<${#PREFETCH_METHODS[@]};i++))
    do
        for ((j=1; j<=$BENCHMARK_NUM; j++))
        do
            sleep 2
            array=($(ps -aux | grep -o  ${PREFETCH_METHODS[i]}))
            echo ${#array[@]} 
            while [ ${#array[@]} -ge 10 ]
            do
                sleep 60
                array=($(ps -aux | grep -o  ${PREFETCH_METHODS[i]}))
            done

            cmd="python my_script.py ${PREFETCH_METHODS[i]} $BENCHMARK_NUM " 
  
            $cmd &

        done
    done
```

Can the above work be done in a python script?  I can use multiple processes to run functions, but I can't control the number of them running (the server has other users, and I don't want to take up all the resources).

How can I do it more efficiently?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a process pool `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and fix the number of processes you want to use (`max_workers` argument). Everything you want to know is included in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).